# Converting a bash column into counts while ignoring characters

Tags: bash, awk

This is a little bit odd but I am trying to counts instances of the character "N" in a column, substituting each occurrence with the current count, leaving other characters intact. For instance:

```
N
N
-
-
N
-
-
N
N
N
```

Should become:

```
1
2
-
-
3
-
-
4
5
6
```

Can't seem to describe this well to find an existing answer, appreciate the help.

Comment: With bash: `declare -i a=0; while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line == "N" ]] && a=a+1 && line=$a; echo "$line"; done < file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{ if ($1=="N") {a++; print a} else {print} }' file
```

Output:

```
1
2
-
-
3
-
-
4
5
6
```

Comment: I golfed this, but don't feel it warrants a separate answer: `awk '{ print $1 == "N" ? ++a : $1 }'`

Comment: @BenjaminW. More golfed `awk '$1 == "N"{$1=++a}1'`

Comment: @123 You can optimize two chars still ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Do you mean removing the spaces? I just left them from your comment.

Comment: @123 Exactly. I know, eye-roll worthy.

Comment: `awk '/^N$/{$1=++c}1'`

Comment: @karakfa Says in question for a specific column tho

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print (/N/?++c:$0)}' file
1
2
-
-
3
-
-
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

try:(clearly based on your shown sample Input_file)

```
awk '/^N$/{sub(/N/,++i);}1'   Input_file
```

So checking a line which starts from character N and then substituting character N with a variable named i whose value is increasing each time a substitution is happening. Then putting 1 will print the current line, mentioning the Input_file then.